# Reading Soap Services in Android

Tags: android, soap

I am a newbie in android world, I am using soap services in my code, I dont know how to read a soap service from a url into my code.
Here is a link http://www.livedrive.com/ResellersService/ResellerAPI.asmx?op=SubDomainValid.

Can any one let me know what values I need to put for these variables
    private static String NAMESPACE = "";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static String URL = "";

also how can I parse the data ?
Regards
Mehroze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get SOAP working in android is to use a service like [wsdl2code](http://wsdl2code.com). All you need to do is drop your asmx url there and it will generate all the classes required to use it in android.

I did have some issues with it but the following steps solved my issues

1. Change VER11 to VER12
2. Comment out the lines which say addMapping unless you are passing a class to the service

I pretty much use wsdl2code whenever i use soap